# Why the string.function() syntax in Python? (lower/upper function)

Tags: python, function, lowercase

I would like to understand some level of intuition for why the `lower()` function in Python requires string inputs to come *before* the function rather than in the brackets. For example

```py
name = "Bob"
name_lowercase = name.lower()
```

In general, I would expect something like

```py
name_lowercase = lower(name)
```

Comment: It is called object oriented programming. You call methods in the context of an object.

Comment: In fact, you can. Try: `str.lower(name)`

Comment: Because it's one of the [`str` methods](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods), as opposed to a free function. It pertains to strings (rather than being generically applicable to many types, like `len`, but an authoritiative answer would need to come from a Python maintainer or language designer.

Comment: "Why" questions on language design are often off-topic here, insofar as they're about satisfying curiosity or registering a complaint, rather than about answering a practical question you actually face that prevents you from writing working code.

Comment: @user523384, I have updated my answer with more realiable source. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

**Updated Answer**

I found this is in the book `Fluent Python (2nd edition)`. Hope this helps.

[image]

**Old Answer**

In my understanding, it's because of the python language's target to maintain **consistency**. As mentioned by @nanofarad, in case of `len()` function you can use it with not just `string` but with `list` and other types as well. Also, if you take another example, let's say `sum()`, you can use it with any `iterable`. So, if you find any built-in function that can be used with objects of multiple types, then they are used in `function(value)` format. But in case of `lower()`, it is used only with `strings`. So, when you find yourself using any method that's specific to a particular object type, then you will be using `object.method()` format. It's simply **pythonic**.